# geoNames api returning SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am using Ajax Jquery to post data to PHP curl, which is performing a request to one of the GeoNames API.

I am getting the following error below after submitting the call:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of
> the JSON data

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $executionStartTime = microtime(true);

    $url='http://api.geonames.org/weatherIcaoJSON?formatted=true&ICAO='.$_REQUEST["getStation"].'&username=myUsername&style=full';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    $decode = json_decode($result,true);    

    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "success";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
    $output['data'] = $decode['geonames'];
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    echo json_encode($output); 

?>
```

Jquery Code:

```
$("#getWeather").click(()=>{
    $.ajax({
        url: "libs/php/getStation.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            getStation: $("#weatherId").val()
        },
        success: function(result){
            if (result.status.name == "ok"){
                console.log(result);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    })
})
```

Html code:

```
    <select id="weatherId">
        <option value="EGLL">Heathrow</option>
        <option value="EGKK">London Gatwick</option>
        <option value="EGSS">London Stanstead</option>
        <option value="EGCB">Manchester</option>
        <option value="EGGW">London Luton</option>
        <option value="EGPH">Edinburgh</option>
        <option value="EGBB">Birmingham</option>
        <option value="EGGD">Bristol</option>
        <option value="EGPF">Glasgow</option>
        <option value="EGAA">Belfast International</option>             
    </select>                               
    <button class="submitBtn" id="getWeather">SUBMIT</button>
```

Here is the geonames API section

Webservice Type : REST

Url : api.geonames.org/weatherIcaoJSON?

Parameters :

- ICAO : International Civil Aviation Organization (ICAO) code
- callback : name of javascript function (optional parameter)
- Result : returns the weather station and the most recent weather observation for the ICAO code

Example http://api.geonames.org/weatherIcaoJSON?ICAO=LSZH&username=demo*

Comment: That kind of error usually means, that you did not actually get valid JSON back. Check what your script returned to the client using your browser’s dev tools, network panel.

Comment: Side note: These parameters: `$output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";` in your generated output are completely superfluous. The browser will return the HTTP status automatically as part of the AJAX response. You don't need to provide it again.